# BufferedInputStream.read() not reliably returning data to my app - data bunches up

Tags: android

My app receives data through a serial port... they're typically small chunks of data. For example, sometimes it 40 bytes, sometimes 60 bytes. All the chunks of data are separated by a second, or possibly even a minute.

I read that using BufferedInputStream is good for reading chunks of data so that the app doesn't create a lot of CPU overhead by reading data byte by byte.

So that's what I did - just like this example: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/ReadFilterFile.shtml

**When it works, it works great!**
My app gets a complete chunk of data - I was worried that I would receive incomplete chunks, but no, to my amazement it's complete chunks.

**However, sometimes it doesn't work so well**
What seems to happen is that a small chunk of data doesn't cause the read() method to complete. When a little bit larger chunk comes along later then finally the read() will return. This is undesirable !

I do not want my app to be denied a chunk of data until another chunk arrives.

**Question:**
How do I ensure that BufferedInputStream.read() returns shortly after a small chunk of data was received ? Is byte-by-byte read the only way ?

Comment: i think it should work, please post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it solved - the solution was to use smaller buffers... taking the roseindia.net sample, the following fixes the read() to always return after a chunk of data:

```
  final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128;
  byBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
  try 
  {
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Filterfile.txt");
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fin, BUFFER_SIZE*2);

  // Now read the buffered stream.
  while (bis.available() > 0) 
  {
  int iBytesRead = bis.read(byBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
  }

  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
  System.err.println("Error reading file: " + e);
  }
```

maybe the 8K default buffer was too large and the small chunks of data didn't reliably pass some threshold ?